# With a HTML table, how to make the first column fixed width and the second and third columns 50% each of the remaining width

Tags: html, css

So imagine I have a space 100px wide which can change. The first column of the table I want fixed at 30px and the second and third columns I want to be 50% each of the remaining width (70px) making them 35px each.

SO when the width of the space changes to 300px, the column widths would be 30px, 135px, 135px (where 135px is 270px divided by two ie 50%).

This is my attempt which isnt working:

```
<table width="100%" >
                    <tr>
                        <td width="30px"> </td>
                        <td align="center" width="25%"></td>
                        <td align="center" width="25%"></td>
                    </tr>
 </table>
```

I have tried various others.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Set the width of the table in px, and then, the size of tds in %.

In this example, you want a total width of 60px.

```
<table width="60px" >
                    <tr>
                        <td width="50%"> </td>
                        <td align="center" width="25%"></td>
                        <td align="center" width="25%"></td>
                    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<table width="100%" >
    <tr>
        <td width="30px" bgcolor="red"></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="blue"></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="green"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/236Lu/)**

Comment: The other two cells will only be equal if their content naturally has the same width.

Comment: Although looking at the duplicate question it suggests that `table-layout: fixed;` will solve that.

Comment: Thanks! This worked! Do I need to use `table-layout: fixed;`? This works fine without `table-layout: fixed;`.

Comment: Hi @Sam. If it works without `table-layout: fixed;`, then you don't need to use it.

Comment: Thanks Barna, it does works without `table-layout: fixed`! This answer surely should be the accepted answer!